# Why when I "write" the image, values change?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary

I have converted an image to a `binary` (0 & 1) image based on some criterion. And, for some pixels, I assigned them the value `-1` as a flag. When I run my program, the result is as expected. But, when I `imwrite` the result (image), I get the values as (0 & 255), and pixels which had the value `-1` are no longer there. Is that to do with `imwrite`? How can I keep my values as is when writing the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

when you `imwrite` each pixel is converted to 8-bits (depends on the file format, but this is usually the case). These 8-bits are of **unsigned** int8, therefore any negative values are truncated to 0.

To overcome this issue, you may want to use only values in the range [0..255] for pixels choosing a specific value **from this range** to be your "flag".

Comment: @hai. Thanks for your reply. I did that, and assigned for instance the value `33`. When I did `imwrite`, such value did not also appear. So, I was back with only the `0` and `255` values. Why is that?

Comment: @Med-SWEng sounds weird. Can you add a **short** code snippet to your question?

Comment: there is no "negative values" in logical array

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put -1 into a logical array.
Suppose we create logical array

```
x = true(2,2);
```

The assignment

```
x(1) = -1;
```

is equal to

```
x(1) = (-1 ~= 0);
```

therefore any nonzero value is converted to `true`;

As for the solution, before you set `flags`, convert the logical array into uint8.

```
img = uint8(255 * img_logical);
img(3,10) = 254; % secret flag
imwrite(img, 'img.jpg');
```

Comment: so why "when I run my program, the result is as expected"? If the problem is as you describe, it should have been apparent while the program was running...

Comment: `imwrite()` converts logical `{false, true}` into uint8 `{0, 255}`. If you set `-1` or `5` into the logical array it will be converted into `true` and then into `255`=white

Comment: @Serg. Thanks for your reply. What does `img(3,10)` refer to? Why `(3,10)'?

Comment: @Serg. Thw image I'm working with is of type 'unit8`. as when I do the following `name=input('image filename: ','s');
img=unit8(imread(name));`, I get the following error: `Undefined function 'unit8' for input arguments of type
'uint8'.`

Comment: Also, for `double` types, I get the following when attempting to convert to `unit8`: `Undefined function 'unit8' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

Comment: @Med-SWEng, `img(3,10) = 254` is just an example how to set a flag into pixel `3x10`.

Comment: @Med-SWEng, there is no `unit8`. It is `uint8`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention what parameters you are using with `imwrite` or which file format you're using, but I suspect it's a single-bit format. That means the only values each pixel can have are `0` or `1`. When you read the image back, the `1` gets converted to `255` but you still only have the two possibilities. While the image is in memory you can set the values however you want, but they will all be converted again when the file is written.